# How can I allow a specific standard user in Ubuntu 11.10 to mount a specific NTFS file system?

Tags: 11.10, mount, users

I want to grant permission one specific standard Ubuntu 11.10 user to be able to mount a specific NTFS drive. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this *only* a specific user, i.e you don't want any other users on the system to mount that specific device?

Comment: @Wesley, right. only 1 drive for only 1 user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a command line to mount the partition into a script, than grant that user the privilege to run the script with sudo. For example

```
#!/bin/sh
# Filename: /usr/local/bin/mount-win

mount -o uid=john,gid=john /dev/sda1 /media/win
```

then

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mount-win
```

in `/etc/sudoers` add the line

```
john ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/mount-win
```

where `john` is the standard user's username.

For ease of use, you can create a launcher for the script with a line

```
Exec=gksu /usr/local/bin/mount-win
```

Comment: Nice solution, I like this.

Comment: the first command: `sudo mount -o uid=john,gid=john /dev/sda1 /media/win`, causes error: `fuse: failed to access mountpoint /media/win: No such file or directory`. what's going on? /dev/sda1 exists, and i replaced john with real user name. i ran the command from admin user terminal.

Comment: @Donotalo: `/media/win` is just an example mount point, you should create a directory under `/media` and use that.

Comment: ok, now i'm getting `Sorry, user john is not allowed to execute '/bin/mount -o uid=john,gid=john /dev/sda5 /media/john-d' as root on Cyanide.` when i execute the script from the user's account. now what?

Comment: @Donotalo: sorry, the script should be called with `sudo` (or `gksu`), and the `sudo` inside the script should be removed. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit disk use per user or group via [disk quotas](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/47). This involves enabling quotas per disk within fstab, and configuring quotas with the tools linked.

Also [see this article](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch28_%3a_Managing_Disk_Usage_with_Quotas) on setting up disk quotas.

Comment: it's not quota i need to set. i've a NTFS partition, which i want only one standard user will be able to mount. i want to set this permission. the user can use the partition in any way s/he likes.